# Backbone.js prints "function String() { [native code] }" instead of model attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js and here is my question.

**First I setup routing:**

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function(){

      var data = {
        member: new Member.Model({ _id: 'some id' })
      };

      _.extend(this, data);
      // Use main layout and set Views.
      app.useLayout("main-layout").setViews({
        ".member": new Member.Views.Start(data)
      }).render();
    },
    routes: {
      "": "index"
    },
    index: function() {
      this.member.fetch();
    }
});
```

On index route this will simply get the start view and add it to the DOM when an element matches the member class. This works just fine. However inside the template I have:

```
<%= model.get('username') %>
```

**And this prints**

```
function String() { [native code] }
```

**instead of the model attribute.** Here is the model and view class:

```
var Member = app.module();

Member.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/Members',
    idAttribute: "_id",
    defaults: {
      _id: null,
      name: String,
      email: String,
      username: String,
      initials: String,
      provider: String,
      provider_id: String,
      confirmed: Boolean,
      provider_avatar: String
    },
    initialize: function(models, options){

    }
  });

Member.Views.Start = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "member/start",
    serialize: function() {
      return { model: this.options.member };
    },        
    initialize: function() {

    }
  });
```

For my project I use the backbone boilerplate https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate  Template enging : https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate/wiki/Working-with-templates

Why do I get this text instead of the model values, and how to fix this?

Comment: Without seeing the Model definition or the template call or what template engine you are using it is hard to help, is username defined as a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of the `username` attribute is `String`:

```
Member.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
    defaults: {
      ...
      username: String,
      ...
```

and `String` is a function:

```
> String
function String() { [native code] }
```

This is what you're seeing (remember, in Javascript you can assign functions to variables).

If you expect the default to be some *value* of type string, you need to change the code like so:

```
Member.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
    defaults: {
      ...
      username: '',
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Model definition you  define all your defaults as functions, one way to fix it is to use actual strings for the defaults,

```
defaults: {
  _id: null,
  name: '',
  email: '',
  username: '',
  initials: '',
  provider: '',
  provider_id: '',
  confirmed: false,
  provider_avatar: ''
},
```

If you type `String` into your browsers console you will get,

```
 function String() { [native code] }
```

That is why your output is how it is.